# prevent race conditions in browser JavaScript page refreshes

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

My web page has auto refresh functionality. The auto refresh is implemented using a timer.

```
GInterValId = window.setInterval("AutoRefresh()",interval);
```

The user can also perform some operations by clicking some buttons on the page. The auto refresh functionality and the user operations are creating race conditions.

I would like to prevent the two opertions (auto refresh and button operations) from happening simultaneously.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why do you auto refresh. Redesign it to not be shit

Comment: Aside: don't pass strings to setInterval and setTimeout. Pass the function directly so you don't use the evil eval : `setInterval(AutoRefresh, interval)`

Comment: @missingno - It may be silly to pass a string to setInterval when you can pass a direct reference to the function, but there's nothing evil about it and no harm or danger comes from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about this:

```
busy = false;

function AutoRefresh() {
    if( busy ) return;
    busy = true;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    busy = false;
}

function ButtonOperation() {
    if( busy ) return;
    busy = true;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    busy = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume what you actually want to happen is for the button operations to complete before the page has auto-refreshed. In which case, I'd make your button operation functions add the operation to a queue, then have the AutoRefresh function run the operations before doing the refresh.